# Check if URL is local file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to check the current URL in a `UIWebView` with the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

    NSLog(@"Current URL: %@", currentURL);

    NSString *loginpage = @"file:///var/mobile/Applications/652BAC0C-DEAE-4695-9195-BE617B9D5106/School%20VLE%20Business.app/login.html";

    if([currentURL isEqualToString:loginpage])
    {
        NSLog(@"Inputting user details...");

        NSString *result;
        result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('#usernamefield').val('%@');", username]];
        result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('#passwordfield').val('%@');", password]];
        result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#submitbutton').click();"];

        NSLog(@"Logged in!");

    }
}
```

But the code in the local URL (`652BAC0C-DEAE-4695-9195-BE617B9D5106` for me) isn't going to be the same for everybody, so how can I do the same check but without the long code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these lines to search in a string:

```
if ([your_complete_string rangeOfString:@"YOUR_SEARCH_STRING"].location != NSNotFound){

    // Do your stuff here if found

}
```

Comment: Though this isn't really what he asked, it really can be a good solution to his question.

Answer (score 9):

This would work as a more general solution of determining whether a given URL is from the local file system or is being loaded remotely:-

```
NSString *str = @"file://var/mobile/Applications/652BAC0C-DEAE-4695-9195-BE617B9D5106/School%20VLE%20Business.app/login.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
    // URL is a (local) file...
}
```

(Which answers the subject of your question *How can I check if URL is local file?*)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *loginpage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"login" ofType:@"html"];
```

Since you're using spaces in your app's (which I recommend you not to do anymore), you can use the following code to simulate those `%20` escape strings:

```
NSString *loginpage = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"login" ofType:@"html"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: Comment out the `NSLog(...)` line and put the following line under `NSString *loginpage ...`: `NSLog(@"URL: [%@]:[%@]", currentURL, loginpage);`

Answer (score -1):

You can find using `fileReferenceUrl`

```
//if local file
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:songsList[index]];
if(url.fileReferenceURL != nil){
    //is local URL
}else{
    //Is live
   url = [NSURL URLWithString:songsList[index]];
}
```

Comment: read proper question after giving the answers. The question of URL check nil or not, check URL is the Local file path or not.